# Центрирование изображения, если текст смещен влево

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой код, который выводит статью со вставленными картинками. У текста стоит выравнивание по левому краю, и оно ставится на изображение. Никакие команды по выравниваю изображения в центре не помогают. В чем может быть проблема?

```css
p {
  margin: 5px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
img{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Текст, много текста
  <br><img width="50px" src="https://media.licdn.com/media/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANbAAAAJDE5NjBkNDk1LTY3ZGQtNDA0NS04YTJiLTdkNmU3NjZiNjI3Mg.png">
  <br> Тут еще много текста</p>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема img вынести из p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```css
p {
  margin: 5px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
img{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Текст, много текста
  <br><center><img width="50px" src="https://media.licdn.com/media/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANbAAAAJDE5NjBkNDk1LTY3ZGQtNDA0NS04YTJiLTdkNmU3NjZiNjI3Mg.png"></center>
  <br> Тут еще много текста</p>
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо, как-то сразу не догадался.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)
Есть ещё возможность сделать по центру через css, если не забуду, то попозже скину ещё вариант.